# compareTo without return in Kotlin doc generics example

Tags: generics, kotlin

I'm reading kotlin doc: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html

In the middle of the page there is an example of "in":

```
interface Comparable<in T> {
    operator fun compareTo(other: T): Int
}

fun demo(x: Comparable<Number>) {
    x.compareTo(1.0) // 1.0 has type Double, which is a subtype of Number
    // Thus, we can assign x to a variable of type Comparable<Double>
    val y: Comparable<Double> = x // OK!
}
```

What does this line "x.compareTo(1.0)" do? Why is there no return value? or omitted something?

Comment: It calls compareTo() on x, with a double as argument. The result is irrelevant because the point of this code snippet is to show you that doing this call is correct, and compiles fine. Of course in real code you generally care about the result, and don't ignore it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Int` return value of the `compareTo` call is just unused — in a real life codebase that would likely be a useless call indeed (unless the caller depends on the side effects of the `compareTo` implementation, which is discouraged to have any).

In the docs sample, the call is simply used to show that, having a `Comparable<Number>`, you can still call its `compareTo` on a `Double` (which is definitely a subtype of `Number`).

Normally, one uses the return value of `compareTo` in a comparison with zero, which checks whether the operands are in the same ordering relationship as the result and zero:

```
// checks whether x is greater than 1.0
if (x.compareTo(1.0) > 0) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Moreover, the operator conventions in Kotlin allow using the comparison operators, such as `x > 1.0`, on a `Comparable<T>`, translating them to an equivalent `compareTo` call with the result compared to zero.